# C# Parallel.ForEach, not working

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I am trying to convert `ForEach` with a `Parallel.ForEach`.

`ForEach`, works perfectly fine and gives the expected result. Where as when I try to use `Parallel.ForEach`, I get an error for the List variable, saying its not available.

What am I doing wrong? I have added comments in the code to explain.

```
 public  class CalssTest
    {

        List<AssetDetails> assets;
        AssetDetails asset;


        private void loadData()
        {
           //Loading Assetdetails here
            //Skipped here to keep the code short. 
        }

        private void cmdValidate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             OrderManager om = new OrderManager();

             using (ATXFunctions atx = new ATXFunctions())
             {
                 //*****THIS WORKS *********//.
                foreach (AssetDetails ad in assets)
                {
                    ad.OrderEntry.OrderType= "A";
                    ad.OrderEntry.Portfolio = "John";
                    ad.OrderEntry.Quantity = 1000;                    
                    ad.Compliance.Result = om.RunCompliance(atx.AtxEngine, ad.StockEntry, ad.OrderEntry);              
                }

                  //*****THIS ERRORS OUT *********//.
                 // Error ::
                 //The name 'assets' does not exist in the current context

                 Parallel.ForEach (assets (ad) =>
                 {
                     ad.OrderEntry.OrderType = "A";
                     ad.OrderEntry.Customer = "John";
                     ad.OrderEntry.Quantity = 1000;
                     ad.Compliance.Result = om.ValidateOrder(ad.StockEntry, ad.OrderEntry);
                 });


             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Missing comma after `assets`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you syntax is incorrect use :

```
    Parallel.ForEach(assets , (ad) =>
    {
                     ad.OrderEntry.OrderType = "A";
                     ad.OrderEntry.Customer = "John";
                     ad.OrderEntry.Quantity = 1000;
                     ad.Compliance.Result = om.ValidateOrder(ad.StockEntry, ad.OrderEntry);
                 });
```